# Display different data from a single field to multiple textbox (VB 2010/MS Acess)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, textbox

I just want to ask this question (the title). I have a column named PR_rating and I need to display the values to TextBoxes according to student ID so one student ID= many PR_rating. My problem is I don't know how to do that. The TextBox just shows all the values in one TextBox. Sorry for my bad English.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class adminEval
    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String
    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Public dr As OleDbDataReader

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
        dataFile = "C:\Users\Billy\Desktop\TH\exampleData.accdb"
        connString = provider & dataFile
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
        myConnection.Open()
        Dim str As String
        str = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE (Stud_no ='" & txtstudnum.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While dr.Read()
            txteng11.Text &= dr(7).ToString() & Environment.NewLine
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be better to use something other than a textbox to store this data. I prefer putting the code into a `datatable` and then load this into a `datagridview`.

Below is an example using your code:

```
'new variables added for this example
dim dataAdapter as New OldDbDataAdapter
dim dataTable as New DataTable
dim dataGrid as New DataGridView

Private Sub btnSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click

    myConnection.Open()

    Dim str as String
    str = "SELECT * FROM [Transaction] WHERE (Stud_no=@studentNum)"
    Dim cmd as OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, my connection)
    'Use parameters to safely fill the SQL string
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@studentNum",OleDbType.String).value = txtstudnum.Text

    dataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd
    'fill the dataTable using the dataAdapter, which has been executed above
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
    'Use the dataTable as the dataGrid's source to add the data into it
    dataGrid.DataSource = dataTable

    myConnection.Close()        

End Sub
```

Above I also use the [OleDbCommand parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx/). This allows you to safely fill your SQL string for execution.

Using a [Data Adapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter(v=vs.110).aspx/) you can put the data into this from your command and use this data to fill a `dataTable`. Once the table is filled you can populate your `dataGridView` on your form (inserted from the toolbox to your form) by setting the table as your `DataSource`.

Apologies if this is not suited to your needs, I usually do this with MySQL, so OleDB is new to me, but similar syntax.

Comment: i cant post the pic, thanks for you reply sir, but i think ill stick in oledb because we need the textboxes in the project. thanks for the reply, it will be useful. sorry for my bad english

Comment: How many textboxes do you have currently? It might be worth putting them into a collection and loop through them to add data in a `For` loop.

Comment: about 20 textbox. can you guide me or give some articles about that sir?

Comment: I would strongly recommend against that amount of textboxes, but if you insist on it then I think searching for something like: "Inserting data into multiple textboxes" or "making an array of textboxes".

Comment: This question/answer may help further as well: [Link to Textbox array](http://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic-net/answers/911321-how-can-i-make-textbox-n-text-visualbasic-net)